# Why isn't this changing the background?

Tags: javascript, css

In detail what I want to do is to change he background with a random value generated by the calcR() Function.
Here is the code I have written to do this.

```
export default class CB {
  constructor() {
    this.backround = "green";
  }
  calcR() {
    this.r1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255 + 1);
    this.r2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255 + 1);
    this.r3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255 + 1);
    console.log(this.r1);
    console.log(this.r2);
    console.log(this.r3);
  }
  cbg() {
    document.body.style.background = `rgb(${this.r1}, ${this.r2}, ${this.r3})`;
  }
}
```

Comment: well ... you've defined a class ... where have you instantiated it? and then run `calcR` before running `cbg`? You'd need to import that class, create an instance, call `calcR` and call `cbg` before that does anything

Comment: Please show how you are using this class - because a class definition doesn't "run"

Comment: Also, check the browser developer tools console for errors

Comment: Click this link to see what am I doing https://codesandbox.io/live/nr865f1

Comment: "sign in required" - so, why not put the code in the question, because nobody is going to sign up just to help

Comment: ClickButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  AudioMedia1.play();
  let moveHeight = move.generateRandomHeight();
  let moveWidth = move.generateRandomWidth();
  move.moveOut(moveHeight, moveHeight);
  console.log(`width:${moveWidth}`);
  console.log(`height:${moveHeight}`);
  cb.calcR();
  cb.cbg();
});

Comment: import AudioHandler from "/src/cls/audio";
import ScreenSize from "/src/cls/ss";
import Move from "/src/cls/move";
import CB from "/src/cls/cb";

Comment: put relevant code **in the question**

Comment: so, you import CB ... and use `cb.clacR()` ... what is `cb`? where is it defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show you an end to end example, this should work:

```js
class CB {
  constructor() {
    this.backround = "green";
  }
  calcR() {
    this.r1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255 + 1);
    this.r2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255 + 1);
    this.r3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255 + 1);
    console.log(this.r1);
    console.log(this.r2);
    console.log(this.r3);
  }
  cbg() {
    document.body.style.background = `rgb(${this.r1}, ${this.r2}, ${this.r3})`;
  }
}

const cbInstance = new CB();
function changeBG() {
  cbInstance.calcR();
  cbInstance.cbg();
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onClick="javascript:changeBG()">Change bg</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this to achieve your result:

```js
class CB {
  constructor() {
    this.backround = "green";
  }
  calcR() {
    this.r1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255 + 1);
    this.r2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255 + 1);
    this.r3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255 + 1);
    this.background = `rgb(${this.r1}, ${this.r2}, ${this.r3})`;
    return this;
  }
  cbg() {
    document.body.style.background = this.background;
    return this;
  }
}

var cb = new CB();

cb.calcR().cbg();
```

EDIT: seeing how you want it to be used, you could refactor the above code this way:

You could do something like this to achieve your result:

```js
class CB {
  constructor() {
    this.backround = "green";
  }
  calcR() {
    this.r1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255 + 1);
    this.r2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255 + 1);
    this.r3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255 + 1);
    this.background = `rgb(${this.r1}, ${this.r2}, ${this.r3})`;
  }
  cbg() {
    document.body.style.background = this.background;
  }
}

var cb = new CB();

cb.calcR();
cb.cbg();
```